# Finding a Devexpress aspxribbon control by name

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I have a very simple devexpress aspxribbon with controls to filter data by date which is built through databinding. I'm trying to create a function on the server side which will take my ribbon object and go through its children and find a control with the given name. The reason I have to use this is because you cannot set the ID or ClientInstanceName properties, which I would normally use, for the aspxribbon through databinding ([here's the list of allowed properties](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument16429)).

My attempt at writing this function was basically just wishful thinking that the implicit conversion from a System Control to a Devexpress RibbonEditItem (so I could access the Name property) would work, which it obviously didn't. Any help would be appreciated!

Here's my XML that serves as the datasource for the ribbon:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TestInterface>
  <Panel Name="FilterTab" Text="Filter">
    <Group Name="DateSelectors" Text="Date Filter">
      <Item Name="DateFrom" ClientInstanceName="DateFrom" ItemType="DateEdit"></Item>
      <Item Name="DateTo" ItemType="DateEdit"></Item>
      <Item Name="FilterSubmit" Text="Filter"></Item>
    </Group>
    <Group Name="PredefinedDateFilters" Text="Pre-Defined Filters">
      <Item Name="FilterYesterday" Text="Yesterday"></Item>
      <Item Name="Filter7" Text="7 Days"></Item>
      <Item Name="Filter30" Text="30 Days"></Item>
    </Group>
  </Panel>
</TestInterface>
```

And here's the function I attempted to build:

```
protected RibbonEditItemBase getbyName(string name, Control parent)
{
    ControlCollection childControls = parent.Controls;
    foreach(RibbonEditItemBase ctrl in childControls)
    {
        //found, return control
        if (ctrl.Name == name)
            return ctrl;

        //recur for child controls
        if (parent.Controls[ctrl.Index].Controls != null)
        {
            RibbonEditItemBase recur = getbyName(name, parent.Controls[ctrl.Index]);
            //found, return control
            if (recur != null)
                return recur;
        }
    }

    return null; //not found, return null
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`RibbonEditItemBase`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebASPxRibbonRibbonEditItemBasetopic) class is not inherited from `Control` class, so it cannot be converted to `Control`. To find particular item by name you can use [`Ribbon`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxRibbonASPxRibbon_Tabstopic)`->`[`Tab`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxRibbonRibbonTab_Groupstopic)`->`[`Group`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxRibbonRibbonGroup_Itemstopic)`->`[`Item`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument15863) hierarchy.
Here is example:

```
protected RibbonEditItemBase getbyName(string name, ASPxRibbon ribbon)
{
    foreach (RibbonTab tab in ribbon.Tabs)
        foreach (RibbonGroup group in tab.Groups)
            foreach (RibbonItemBase item in group.Items)
            {
                var edit = item as RibbonEditItemBase;

                if (edit != null && edit.Name == name)
                    return edit;
            }


    return null; //not found, return null
}
```

Comment: Thanks! For some reason, the return type RibbonEditItemBase would always return null, so I got rid of the edit part and changed the return type to RibbonItemBase since it has pretty much the same properties and that worked fine.